# how to check thru code, if a field is referred / used anywhere in any of our apex code / vf page / component?

Tags: apex, custom-field

how to check thru code, if a field is referred / used anywhere in any of our apex code / vf page / component ?

Assume I have a field called ApplicationNumber__c

Say I have a list of apex classes :-

a,b,c,d,e,f

out of which a,b,c are referring/using the field ApplicationNumber__c and d,e,f are not.

same way, say I have a list of pages (probably using standard controller) :-

w,x,y,z

out of which w,x is using this field and y,z is not.

I know if I try to delete this field, it tells me where all the field is referred. Is there any way to fetch this information thru apex code?

I know that this could be done through metadata api and eclipse. But it would be great if we could do that through apex. any suggestions?

I also came across an appexchange tool called FieldTrip which does this.

But I want to build something custom, like a visualforce page, where I will just choose my application name and it should list all fields of that app, that are unused and this has to be done through apex.

So am just asking for a hint as to how I can get the fields referenced in classes,triggers and other components through apex.

Comment: It's possible to query each Apex Class and apply a regular expression against a list of known fields, which might generically tell you if a field may be used, but that doesn't cover Visualforce pages, components, custom links, and so on. The metadata API is the most appropriate way to do this, and that means that pure Apex Code is out of the question. It is entirely possible, though, to do this in JavaScript, if you felt like torturing yourself.

Comment: If you want access to the Metadata API from Apex, take a look at this, https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi. What your wanting to do is quite extensive though, you maybe better doing this in Java perhaps in Heroku as a REST service that can be called from your VF page.

Answer (score 7):

In Eclipse, go to your workspace and press Control + H, then search for the field in the workspace. If it's referenced somewhere it should come up in the results.

Comment: Actually I need a list of all fields that are not used in code. so I can't search each field one by one through eclipse. thats the reason I was asking for the approach to get the referenced information through apex code.

Comment: I see, I would do that using the metadata API. I would create a script that downloads classes,triggers,vf pages and list of fields per object, then look for each field in those components. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the info but it would be great if we could do that in apex.

Comment: @Sathya So did you find any solution? If yes, please do share :)

Answer (score 4):

Its possible to query all the apex class body and Vf page body and then look for the required Field using some string method . This is how you find that if its referred and then to delete it its with Metadata API I believe.[image: This is the snapshot of how i did it]

Comment: How did you run that query?

Comment: private List<apexClass> lstClasses = [select Name, Body from ApexClass]; like this i fetch class body.  then i get the field name using Schema.DescribeSObjectResult call i get field details. then search that field (say ApplicationNumber__c) like lstClasses[0].body.contains('ApplicationNumber__c'). This will say if its referred or not . then delete with metadata API if required.

Comment: Would you add that to your answer? You could also package that up with a VF UI; it'd be a useful utility for many people.

Comment: @KeerthanTantry: Quick doubt, how would you know if the field is from this object?? There could be a field with the same API name from other object as well..

Comment: Ya definitely. I am into some issue with metadata API for deleting the non referred  fields. Soon i will package once it is done. but getting above result is much more straight forward @Mike chale

Comment: @theGreatDanton I have a drop down shown there. When i chose the particular object i then get all fields using  Schema.DescribeSObjectResult call on that object . That means it corresponds to chosen object.

Comment: @KeerthanTantry: That's correct. As in case of the screenshot you have selected candidate__c object and the corresponding fields are displayed. THen you query the apexClass and see if the field's API name is present in the class body. Now consider the field city__c, this could be present in many objects. Now when the code runs it checks if  'city__c' is contained in the class body, but it will never know if the city__c belonged to which object. I hope I am clear :)

Comment: Yea I got you now. But may be we can even search for the object names in the body. That also may not give 100% perfect result. May need some workaround. :)

Comment: Consider the [Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/index.htm), instead, if you're going to build it right. This new API actually *tells* you what's being referenced. The Developer Console uses this to build the "references" links when you click on an item to open.

Comment: @Soberano wouldn't you hit limit of 100 SOQL queries in this context? as you will be querying blob field so the batch size will become 1 and hence you will need to go through 1 class at a time to find reference ie you will be able to search only 100 classes and then too many soql queries error will come up? Any workarounds (Action poller might be one)? or am I missing something?

Comment: @ChiragMehta I am really not sure which blob field you are telling. When one object is chosen it will actually get all fields and then query all classes at one shot then iterate each class body to see if the field is being referenced. Only thing we need to take care is "What if same field name exists in different objects (Possible scenario)". We wont query one class every time.

Comment: I'm referring to BODY field which stores actual lines of code. Are you referring that Select Id,Body from ApexClass will give me all available apex classes in one query itself? To my knowledge when you include Body field in soql then you get only one result per query ie batch size is reduced to one. Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I dont know if you are asking the same. I tried this query in workbench and i got 5 rows of data with body :"SELECT Body,BodyCrc,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Id FROM ApexClass  limit 5". It never returned just 1.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty old thread but adding another option. I have a free and open source app that scans the fields in your Org and returns the components it's used in (Workflows, Processes, Page Layouts, Apex etc).

Keep in mind that returning fields in Apex and VF is not 100% accurate, as a field with the same API name on different objects would return as being found in a class, even though it might not (as others have mentioned).

Keep it mind it can also take quite a while to run on large Orgs.

App: http://schemalister.herokuapp.com/

Source Code: https://github.com/benedwards44/schemalister